# How to create a micropage - just for the fun of it (without MWE)

Tags: longtable, scaling

I once wrote a file to make "micropages", the only trick was, to scale down all the measures. It's easy. Those micropages were filled into the cells of a longtable.
(At this time, it does not make sense to post the whole files.) The "micropages" were accessible, they were **not** just images or thumbnails.

Now, here's the question:

Can someone imagine a way to get a whole page (and all the pages) of a document scaled down to micropages, to be filled into a table, still editable?

Comment: @David Carlisle Please take a look at this. :-)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You first claim that making micropages is easy, then you are asking how to do it? What do you mean with "still editable"?

Comment: it is trivial to scale a pdf text down to whatever size dot you want (what has longtable got to do with it?)  it is really impossible to guess what your question is currently.  (try putting `\mag 20` at the top of a file for example

Comment: what do you mean by "scale down the measures" ? You do not need to do anything to the page markup, just scale the resulting document

Comment: @Marcel Krüger  I may write a page and I may write a micropage. To scale down a page, I have to copy it and scale down the measures. What I am asking is, how to scale down without copying. "Editable" means, that a given "micropage" should change everytime, when the "normalpage" is changed.

Comment: @David Carlisle This was not about scaling a document.

Comment: ??? then clarify your question:-) what does "a  whole page (and all the pages) of a document scaled down" mean if it is not asking to scale a document, sorry I do not understand the question at all, clearly.

Comment: @David Carlisle It is not easy to explain, I'll better try to make a MWE.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is looking for a kind of appendix (or table of contents) which is a tabular made with reduced size pages of the rest of the document. But maybe I haven't understood...

Comment: I don't know why this is so unclear to you. Every document has pages. The pages are ejected by \eject or \shipout. I try to have every page as a copy scaled down to a certain size and to be filled into the cells of a table. It is a kind of microfiche.